# Self-referential integral simplifies to an exponential function

Tags: integration

> A differentiable function $f(x)$ is defined such that, for all values of $x$ in its domain, $f(x) = \int_8^{x^3} f\left(\sqrt[3]{t}\right)\ \mathrm{d}t$.

Apparently the domain is all real numbers, the derivative $f'(x) = 3x^2 f(x)$, and $f(x) = 3 e^{x^3 - 8}$.

1. Why doesn't $f(x)$ diverge or equal infinity at any point? The integral calls $f(x)$ recursively.
2. How do you find the derivative?
3. How can I recognize and rearrange self-referential integrals like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any continuous function on a closed interval $[a,b]$ is integrable. To differentiate note that $f(x)=h(x^{3})$ where $h(x)=\int_8^{x} f(t^{1/3}) dt$ and apply Chain Rule.

Comment: Why is it continuous?

Comment: Differentiable functions are continuous and compositions of continuous functions are continuous.

Answer (score 1):

The derivative can be found using Leibnitz's rule:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}F(x,t)dt = \frac{db}{dt}F(x,b(x))-\frac{da}{dt}F(x,a(x))+\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}F(x,t)dt$$

In this case, $a(x) = x^3$, $b(x) = 8$, $F(x,t) = f(t^{1/3})$. So

$$\frac{df}{dx} = \frac{d}{dx}\int_{8}^{x^3}f(t^{1/3})dt = (3x^2)f(x)-(0)f(2)+\int_{8}^{x^3}(0)dt = 3x^2f(x)$$